# How can I transform this (100, 100) numpy array into a grayscale sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I'm trying to make a special kind of grating called a Gabor patch, an example of which can be found at the bottom of [this tutorial](http://www.icn.ucl.ac.uk/courses/MATLAB-Tutorials/Elliot_Freeman/html/gabor_tutorial.html) whose code I ported to python.

Using matplotlib's `imshow` function, I obtain the following patch.[image: python-generated Gabor patch displayed with matplotlib's imshow]

While the coloring is different, I suspect that this has to do with how matplotlib displays numerical values.  In essence, this image is a 2D, 100-by-100 pixel array containing values from `-1.0` to `1.0` (inclusive).  If anybody would like to try manipulating the array in question, I've saved it as a pickle object [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/g.pickle).

**My question is as follows:** How can I transfer this array to a pygame surface while ensuring that the following conditions are met?

1. The coloring is converted to grayscale coloring (*c.f.*: the last image in the first link)
2. The solution must employ pygame version `1.9.1release`.  For some inexplicable reason, I can't find a way to install `1.9.2` on my OS (Ubuntu 13.04).  There appear to be no PPAs and pygame is evidently not on PIP.

Thank you very much in advance, and please let me know if I can provide additional information!

**Edit**

Regarding @Veedrac's solution (which is remarkably similar to my own), here is what my patch looks like when using the grayscale colormap in matplotlib's `imshow`.  This is what I **would like** to have:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.cm as cm

figure()
imshow(g, cm=cm.Greys_r)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: What format are the pixels in the pickled object? They load as floats, but what's the `float32` → `RGB` mapping?

Comment: @Veedrac, they're *supposed* to be percentages of gray, so they would map to something roughly equivalent to an RGB tuple of `(px * 255, px * 255, px * 255)`.  That big red patch in the middle of the grating should be pure white at it's center, so blue=>black and red=>white.

Comment: I don't know much about `pygame`, but I believe you just want to use `pygame.surfarray.make_surface`: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.make_surface You may need to rescale your floats to 8 or 16-bit integers, but that's easy to do.

Comment: @Veedrac - The function exists in 1.9.1 as well. 1.9.2 just added array interface (i.e. it will read anything with `__array__` defined) support, I think.

Comment: @JoeKington, `make_surface` does exist in `1.9.1release` but unfortunately produces a patch that looks like the patch produced by Veedrac's answer below.

Comment: @blz - That's because your data ranges from -1 to 1.  `make_surface` appears to expect positive integers.  Try rescaling first. E.g. `new_data = (255 * (your_data - your_data.min()) / your_data.ptp()).astype('uint8')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy
import pickle
import pygame

surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
```

Get the pixels, convert to RGBA. Using Joe Kington's reminder that the data ranges from -1 to 1:

```
base = (pickle.load(open("g.pickle"))+1)/2 * 255
base = base[..., numpy.newaxis].repeat(4, -1).astype("uint8")
```

Copy the data across

```
numpy_surface = numpy.frombuffer(surface.get_buffer())
numpy_surface[...] = numpy.frombuffer(base)
del numpy_surface
```

Show it with:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

and you get

[image]

---

And simplified, once again thanks to Joe Kington's input, using `make_surface`:

```
import numpy
import pickle
import pygame

base = (pickle.load(open("g.pickle"))+1) * 128
base = base[..., None].repeat(3, -1).astype("uint8")

surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(base)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

---

The `base[..., None]` is normally spelt `base[..., numpy.newaxis]`, but seeing as that was the only instance of `numpy` I just "expanded the constant" so as to not need `numpy`. It didn't work, though, as the code breaks if you don't import `numpy` with a `IndexError: bytes to write exceed buffer size`. Thanks, `numpy`.

The `...` means "the whole of all of the axis before this point", so you can replace `[3:2]`, `[:, 3:2]` and `[:, :, :, 3:2]` with `[..., 3:2]`. In fact, `...` was introduced to Python for this very reason.

The `None`, or `numpy.newaxis`, slices a new axis (duh). This will transform `[a, b, c]` into `[[a], [b], [c]]`, for example. This is needed because we then `repeat` along this new axis.

Basically, looking at one row, we have

```
114, 202, 143, ...
```

and we want

```
[114, 114, 114], [202, 202, 202], [143, 143, 143], ...
```

so our `[..., None]` got us to

```
[114], [202], [143], ...
```

and we just `repeat` `3` times in axis `-1`. Axis `-1` is, of course, the last axis, which is the `numpy.newaxis`.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely the problem I've been encoutering.  The resulting grating looks nothing like a grayscale version of the colored grating above, and even less like the grayscale image in the first link.

I can confirm that my code produces similar output to the matlab function from which it's derived (with only the trivial and expected floating-point errors)

Comment: as mentioned in my last comment, I checked that the two functions were producing quasi-identical output.  It's as close as you can reasonably expect when dealing with floats.

Besides, if you look at the color version of the patch, it looks right -- it's just the colors that are off.  In the image you've generated (which is exactly the same one I'm getting), it's obvious that something is getting distorted.

Comment: @Veedrac - You're assuming his data ranges from 0-1. It ranges from -1 to 1. You just need to properly rescale the data to uint8's.

Comment: @Joe Kington, ahhh you might be onto something here!  Could you please demonstrate how to do so?

Comment: @blz - Just subtract the min, divide by the range, multiply by 255, and then cast to uint8. E.g. instead of just doing `(data * 255).astype('uint8')`, do `(255 * (data - data.min()) / data.ptp()).astype('uint8')`. Also, I don't think you need to tile the 2D array to 3D RGBA. Just pass in the 2D array.

Comment: @JoeKington, Brilliant!  Thank you very much!

Thanks to you as well, Veedrac!

Comment: @Veedrac, Could you please explain the `base[..., None].repeat(3, -1)` portion of your code?  What exactly is going on there (particularly with the `...`) ?